# Ordering an NSMutableDictionary with multiple keys

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` with two keys. One for titles (e.g. 'Test') and one for distances (e.g. '200' miles).

How can I order these values by the nearest or furthest distance. I would need both the title AND distance value indexes to change when they are ordered.

So this would be the regular version of the `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
Titles: (
    "Test1"
    "Test2"
    "Test3"
)

Distances: (
    "240"
    "43"
    "482"
)
```

And the ordered version (for nearest distances):

```
Titles: (
    "Test2"
    "Test1"
    "Test3"
)

Distances: (
    "43"
    "240"
    "482"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help but feel that what you want is an NSArray of NSDictionaries, or an NSArray of custom objects. This design feels really awkward and creates extra work — because the only real answer if you structure your data this way is "Create a custom API around the whole thing that very carefully manages this invariant, and then only ever mutate this data structure through that interface."

Comment: So apart from what you have mentioned, there is no way of sorting both of these keys?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: No, because there is no real association between the values in the "Titles" array and the values in the "Distances" array. They're two independent collections. If you want to only ever mutate them together, that will require custom code. That's why I'm suggesting making them into one collection, because then they *are* associated and you get the behavior for free.

Comment: Could I maybe use dictionaryWithObjectsForKeys: - would that make the association easier?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: I don't see how the method you use to create the data structure makes any difference as long as you're creating this same data structure. The point is that your data structure has two separate arrays. Arrays don't have any "Pretend like you and this other array are really a unified array of pairs" method. That's why you either need to create this functionality yourself or actually make the two arrays into one. Why are you resistant to that idea? Is there some constraint here that we should know about?

Answer (score 1):

As @Chuck says an array of pairs is the obvious structure if sorting these two arrays, or keeping them sorted, is a key operation. If however it is a rare operation and there are very good reasons to keep it as a 2-array dictionary then you can achieve your goal as follows:

1. Create a new array (NSArray or plain C-array) with the same number, *n*, of elements as your arrays.
2. Fill this array with the integers 0 to (*n* - 1)
3. Custom sort that array ordering two values based on looking up values in the `Distances` array at the same indices and comparing those.
4. When done you have an array of indices being the permutation you wish to apply to your two arrays.
5. Permute both arrays.

But an array of pairs will be easier...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST1", @"TITLE", [NSNumber numberWithInt:240], @"DISTANCE", nil];
NSDictionary *dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST2", @"TITLE", [NSNumber numberWithInt:43], @"DISTANCE", nil];
NSDictionary *dic3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TEST3", @"TITLE", [NSNumber numberWithInt:482], @"DISTANCE", nil];

NSSortDescriptor *distanceSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"DISTANCE" ascending:YES]; //Set 'NO' to order from biggest to lowest

NSArray *sortedArrayOfDic = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic1, dic2, dic3, nil] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:distanceSort, nil]];

NSLog(@"%@", sortedArrayOfDict);
```

The output would be an array of dictionaries sorted by distances, something like:

```
"43", "TEST2"
"240", "TEST1"
"482", "TEST3"
```